# Soundcloud - application registration - link doesn't work

Tags: authentication, registration, soundcloud

We need to register a new app to connect our soundcloud profile to our website but the link (https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfNxc82RJuzC0DnISat7n4H-G7IsPQIdaMpe202iiHZEoso9w/closedform) doesn't work anymore.
How can we proceed?

We started our authentication from this link https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide and the first step is registration.

Answer (score 1):

I had to contact their support team to register a new app. To speed up the process, you can send the following info about your app in your message:

- SoundCloud account under which the app shall be registered
- App name
- App description
- App Purpose
- Redirect URL

Answer (score 1):

This is from my successful app registration experience within the past month.

To get access to their API, I had to register a new app to get the "Client ID" and "Client Secret" codes. The situation is still the same - the Google Form says they are no longer accepting new registration requests.

BUT I sent an email to their support team (support@support.soundcloud.com) telling them that I wanted to register a new app to use their API. I let them know:

The App Name
The App Description (briefly)
How I intended to use their API
The account I wanted to register the app under.

I received an answer from SoundCloud Support within 48 hours advising the app had been created and the details were under https://soundcloud.com/you/apps.

Hope this helps, and if not you, hopefully it helps someone else in the future!

Answer (score 0):

That has been the situation since at least 2020, the registration link just points to that Google doc, it's been crickets from Soundcloud.